# jQuery — Stripping URLs from Text Strings

Tags: jquery, regex

```js
var url = new RegExp('^(https?://)?([da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})([/w .-]*)*/?$');
var title = $(".something").text().replace(url, '');

console.log(title)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something">
Blah blah blah https://example.com/ ha ha ha.
</div>
```

Output I'm getting:

```
Blah blah blah https://example.com/ ha ha ha.
```

Output I want:

```
Blah blah blah ha ha ha.
```

Is the format of my expression itself wrong or the very way in which I'm trying to use regex within jQuery or something else?

I'm unable to remove URLs from the string.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the text within your `.something` element? What do you expect the result to be? What are you actually seeing?

Comment: _"`[da-z.-]`"_  why is "d" here? It's already included in `a-z`

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to match the entire string by using the start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors. Also, `/w` should be `\\w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to pick apart your regex to help you there, but I am able to grab the regex I use regularly to match urls. This also removes the extra spaces afterwards.

```js
const urlPattern = new RegExp("([a-z0-9-]+\:\/+)([^\/\s]+)([a-z0-9\-@\^=%&;\/~\+]*)[\?]?([^ \#\r\n]*)#?([^ \#\r\n]*)","g")
let title = $(".something").text().replace(urlPattern, '').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
console.log('before:', $(".something").text());    
console.log('after:', title)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something">
Blah blah blah https://example.com/ ha ha ha.
</div>
```